# Angular - An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot read property 'createAsExpression' of undefined

Tags: angular-cli

Angular:
"@angular/cli": "^14.0.3"

When I try to run the application getting below error message.

[image]

Comment: I'm getting the same thing. Were you able to resolve this? My angular version is 9.1.13 because most of my projects use this version but then I installed the latest version of angular locally (14.0.4) and I'm trying to run ng build and I'm getting the exact same error. Let me know if you were able to solve it.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you should update Typescript. After update to Angular version 9.

```
ng update typescript
```

https://update.angular.io/?v=8.0-14.0

Answer (score 2):

I got this problem too, i were update **typescript** version to *4.7.4* and it's work

Answer (score 0):

this issue is due to bad version of TS that is not compatible; find the correct version and update your dependencies
This work for me

> sudo ng update typescript@4.8.2